# static propery in winforms c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, properties

I have a WinForms application.
In this app I have some Forms and Static class which have a **public static property**
and some public static methods that need the property to be set because the forms use on
those methods.

Now, if I set this property in the First Form, so when I use some methods on the 
Second Form will I get an error or the property is still set (saved the first set on the first form)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really want is a Singleton instead of a static class. There is some overlap, but if I understand your desire correctly, the Singleton is the proper approach. See this SO post: for more info and a code listing: [Example of Singleton pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585022/example-of-singleton-pattern/2585062#2585062)

Comment: +1 on moving the functionality out of the form - it's debatable whether singletons are preferable over static helper classes...though I think for the most part people prefer singletons.  This is an interesting post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765060/why-use-a-singleton-instead-of-static-methods

Comment: wow! thank you both Todd Sprang and NDJ

Comment: @NDJ, check out this in-depth discussion: http://leedumond.com/blog/singletons-vs-static-classes/ and even more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241339/when-to-use-static-classes-in-c-sharp

Comment: @ToddSprang for more details, I have a database, and in those two forms I can insert or update data into a different tables, so what I want is to have one instance of the DB ConnectionString and each of the form will call to the appropriate method to insert the data

Comment: @ToddSprang the first link is broken..

Comment: @Elior: Oh, what you really want to do is build a data-access layer (separate referenced .csproj). Basically something that will provide a method to do things like UpdateCustomers(CustomerInfo customerInfo) { ... }. Here are details in ASP.NET, but the principle applies to WinForms too. http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/introduction/creating-a-data-access-layer-cs More details are way beyond the scope of a SO reply. :) Note your app.config allows you to store the connection string in a central place: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bf7sd233(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @ToddSprang so just to be calm, is the static class I created for queries is a good solution?

Comment: @Elior IMO without a lot more info I would say not. I would build a data-access layer as described. I realize this may be more than you want to do, but it's a decision between good architecture and just-works architecture. Your static class should meet your need, but it's probably not the best approach.

Answer (score 2):

Static variable stay saving its value

Answer (score 1):

The property is still set. This is how static properties are actually work.

Answer (score 1):

Static Fields are shared across the App Domain. As a result, the second form will have access to the data set by the first form.